# R blogdown : deploy with github actions on gh-pages

Tags: r, github-actions, blogdown

Is there a repo somewhere where a `blogdown` website is builded by `github action` and where the `public` directory is then commited to github pages ? I would like to see the `.github/workflow` :)

Thanks !

Comment: I don't have the answer but if you have some time, here's a list of blogs made with blogdown: https://awesome-blogdown.com/ Maybe you will find what you want by exploring their repo

Comment: I believe `blogdown` uses Hugo, and it's my understanding that github pages support it. I believe that is why people often use Netlify to render their website. So I'm not sure that you can solely use github or github pages to build a blogdown website. But I may be wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, using the research functions on github yields a bunch of repo that do it :

https://github.com/search?q=blogdown+path%3A.github%2Fworkflows

So from these examples, the question is solved.

Edit : It's a private repo, but i've copied the `.github/worklfows/build.yaml` file into this gist : https://gist.github.com/lrnv/17f2c721f4ac30ce55ae335cb83b6639

What it does is that is compiles the blogdown that is pushed on `master` and deploy the `public` repo onto the `gh-pages` branches. I use it for my blog, https://actuarial.science . The `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` variable is automaticaly setted up by github itself, you have nothing to do about it.

Comment: Would be cool if you could share some more details of your solution (and whatever gotchas you discovered, e.g. storing of secrets)